# Does a Canada PR card holder require a transit visa for London Heathrow airport?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, germany, transit-visas, canadian-residents

I have an Indian passport and a Canadian PR card. I am travelling back to Canada from India with stopovers in Frankfurt and London. Do I need a transit visa for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the UK, if you have a Canadian resident permit issued after June 28, 2002 you do not need a visa for transit, otherwise, you have to apply for a Direct Airside Transit Visa ([DATV](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa))

> Exemptions
>
> You don’t need a visa if you have one of the following:
>
> a resident permit issued by Canada after 28 June 2002
>
> [link](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/somewhere_else/no)

For Frankfurt please refer to this [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27491/do-i-need-a-transit-visa-in-frankfurt-germany-on-the-way-to-india).